# Why 500 Server Error in google app engine after deploy?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-crawler

My script runs perfectly on Google app engine's localhost, but on deploying the script shows following error on cloud (appspot.com):
"Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

Here is my code:

```
import webapp2
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')
import requests
from bs4 import *
import re
import smtplib
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from google.appengine import runtime

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.write("hello")

    #urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)

  def spider():
    count = 1
    href = 'www.example.com'
    while count <= 2:
      new_url = href
      new_source_code = urlfetch.fetch(new_url, deadline=60)
      new_plain_text = new_source_code.content
      new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_plain_text)
      for new_link in new_soup.find_all('table'):
        for new_link1 in new_link.find_all('a'):
          new_href = 'www.example.com' + new_link1.get('href')
          new1_url = new_href
          new1_source_code = urlfetch.fetch(new1_url, deadline=60)
          new1_plain_text = new1_source_code.content
          new1_soup = BeautifulSoup(new1_plain_text)
          for new1_link in new1_soup.find_all('tbody'):
            for new1_link1 in new1_link.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'title'}):
              new1_title = new1_link1.string
              new1_title = new1_title.strip()
              new1_href = 'www.example.com' + new1_link1.get('href')
              self.response.write(new1_title)
              self.response.write(new1_href)
    count = count + 1

  spider()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I just want to print the url by crawling, I can see the url on localhost but not on app engine after deploying which shows me error.

Comment: What's in the error log on the server?

Comment: @stark it showed me "elif self.exception:
DeadlineExceededError" in the error log.

Answer (score 2):

For an auto-scaling App Engine module, the deadline is 60 seconds.  In your sample code, you have two URL Fetch requests, each within a loop and each with a deadline of 60s.  Assuming you are not running on a basic scaling or manual scaling instance, you will probably find that you are seeing this exception after 60 seconds.  Even one timeout on the remote host will cause you to exceed your front end deadline.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) will give you the deadlines for different instance scaling types.

However, you may wish to use task queues to help break up the work into manageable, 'retry-able' chunks.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to it, what should I exactly do?

Comment: Some of the comments in the answers to [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610208/fetching-a-lot-of-urls-in-python-with-google-app-engine) should help.

Answer (score 2):

Each request in Google App Engine has a maximum hard limit of 60 seconds, so for anything longer than that you will get the [`DeadlineExceededError`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors).

If you know that upfront that you requests will take more time then you will have to use [Tasks API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/python/getting_started_with_tasks_api) where you can run things up to 10 minutes. Lastly if you want something much longer that take a look on the [Backends API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Billing_quotas_and_limits) where you can run things up to 24 hours.