# Fetching a lot of urls in python with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

In my subclass of RequestHandler, I am trying to fetch range of urls:

```
class GetStats(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self): 

    lastpage = 50   
    for page in range(1, lastpage):
        tmpurl = url + str(page)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(tmpurl, timeout=5)
        html = response.read()
        # some parsing html
        heap.append(result_of_parsing)  

    self.response.write(heap)
```

But it works with ~ 30 urls (page is loading long but it is works).
In case more than 30 I am getting an error:

*Error: Server Error*

*The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.*

*Please try again in 30 seconds.*

Is there any way to fetch a lot of urls? May be more optimal or smth?
Up to several hundreds of pages?

**Update:**

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse every single page. I found this traceback in gae logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gae/1.379703839015039430/main.py", line 68, in post
heap = get_times(tmp_url, 160)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~gae/1.379703839015039430/main.py", line 106, in get_times
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  File "libs/bs4/__init__.py", line 168, in __init__
self._feed()
  File "libs/bs4/__init__.py", line 181, in _feed
self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "libs/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 56, in feed
super(HTMLParserTreeBuilder, self).feed(markup)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 114, in feed
self.goahead(0)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 155, in goahead
startswith = rawdata.startswith
 DeadlineExceededError
```

Comment: Are all the request done to same server/domain name?

Comment: @jDourlens Yes, it is.

Comment: do all your requests complete in under 60 seconds? You only have 60 seconds to return a request. Try putting this to a task or similar.

Comment: The server might block multiple access to his page in short amount of time from same client. Maybe for ddos or scrapping protection.. There is not much you can do as reauesting with different clients or waiting between calls (sleeping)

Comment: @jDourens So, I tested it with urllib2 just from local script on pc (without google app engine). It is works fine.

Comment: Look in the logs and provide more information about error. It could be just deadline error from app engine

Comment: ofc that's what it is ;)

Comment: Sorry i don't know enough on appengine but look about "quotas and limit" maybe

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi Where can I find it?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Quotas_and_limits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's failing because you only have 60 seconds to return a response to the user and I'm going to guess it's taking longer then that.

You will want to use this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

to create a task that has a 10 minute time out. Then you can return instantly to the user and they can "pick up" the results at a later time via another handler (that you create). If collecting all the URLs takes longer then 10 minutes you'll have to split them up into further tasks.

See this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors

to understand why you cannot go longer then 60 seconds.

Comment: How can I catch the moment then my job is finished? For showing result to user.

Comment: On the initial request send them to a URL where you will later make the result available (e.g. /result/job1001 ). Then write some Javascript to refresh that page from the client's side every 10 seconds. Then, when the results are available, they will be displayed within 10 seconds the user. There are of course other options.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Might come from Appengine quotas and limits.
Sorry for previous answer:

As this looks like a protection from server for avoiding ddos or scrapping from one client. You have few options:

- Waiting between a certain number of queries before continuing.
- Making request from several clients who has different IP address and sending information back to your main script (might be costly to rent different server for this..).
- You could also watch if website as api to access the data you need.

You should also take care as the sitowner could block/blacklist your IP if he decides your request are not good.